# JS.InvokeAsync do not return anything i C# ASP Core Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to read window.devicePixelRatio in javascript from C# in ASP Core Blazor.

This is my javascript in wwwroot/index.html:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function PixelRatio()
        {
            return window.devicePixelRatio;
        }
    </script>
    ...
```

And in Index.razor, I trying to call it like this:

```
    @inject IJSRuntime JS
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        if (firstRender)
        {
            GetDevicePixelRatio();
        }
    }

    private async Task GetDevicePixelRatio()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetDevicePixelRatio Calling"); // This shows in Output-log

        m_dpiScale = await JS.InvokeAsync<double>("PixelRatio");

        Console.WriteLine("GetDevicePixelRatio Called with value " + m_dpiScale); // This is not called.
    }
```

I expected the returnvalue be 2.5, but the second Console.WriteLine is not called, I dont know if the InvokeAsync is hanning, or if it throws an silence exception, but nothing i can see.

I can debug in javascript in function PixelRatio() but nothing happens when it returns.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code. It works for me.

Comment: This could be an issue: `GetDevicePixelRatio()` is async, so you should call it with `await`. To do so, you need to override `OnAfterRenderAsync()` instead of `OnAfterRender()`.